# Status of Patent

Tags: us20170205785

In reference to the patent: [US20170205785](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170205785)

When is this patent going to be granted?

Answer (score 2):

When and if the examiner finds it fit for granting.

This process can take a few months up to many years.

Some applications never become granted.

There's no way for us to know more.

Comment: It looks like the questioner is one of the inventors. My experience for US patents is a minimum of 3 years from filing although I acknowledge it could possibly be less.

Comment: @EricShain then op should ask their attorney or at least the person communicating with the office because the application received a non final rejection. You could add an answer explaining the prosecution, patent highway etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your lawyer should be able to obtain an estimate for the first office action date.  Although the examiner issues the estimate, it is often inaccurate.  If you are in a hurry to get it issued, you may want to ask your lawyer to consider filing a continuation as a "Track One" application.  I've had those issue in well under six months.